# How do I set a certain column in a data table to be the default sorted column?

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

Currently using the lightning-datatable component to display 3 columns that can all be sorted by ascending and descending order. There doesn't seem to be a column that is automatically sorted when the data table is displayed, but I want to set "status" as the default sorted column. How would I go about implementing this?

*myComponent.html*

```
<template>
   <lightning-card>
      <template if:true={data}>
         <lightning-datatable
           key-field="id"
           data={data}
           columns={columns}
           sorted-by={sortBy}
           sorted-direction={sortDirection}
           default-sort-direction={defaultSortDirection}
           onsort={handleSortData}
           hide-checkbox-column="false">
        </lightning-datatable>
      </template>
   </lightning-card>
</template>
```

*myComponent.js*

```
const columns = [
    { label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Subject', sortable: "true" },
    { label: 'Date', fieldName: 'Date', sortable: "true"},
    { label: 'Status', fieldName: 'Status', sortable: "true" }
];

export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {

    defaultSortDirection = 'asc';

    @track columns = columns;
    @track sortBy = 'status';
    @track sortDirection = 'asc';
    @api caseData;

    @wire(getCases) caseList({error, data}) {
        this.caseData = data;
    }

    handleSortData(event) {
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        this.sortData(event.detail.fieldName, event.detail.sortDirection);
    }
 
    sortData(fieldName, sortDirection) {
        let fieldName = this.sortBy;
        let sortDirection = this.sortDirection;
        let parseData = [...this.data];

        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldName];
        };

        let isReverse = sortDirection === 'asc' ? 1: -1;

        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; 
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });

        this.data = parseData;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a default attribute for each:

```
@track sortBy = 'status';
@track sortDirection = 'asc';
```

Then call the sort function in the wire handler:

```
@wire(getCases) caseList({error, data}) {
    this.caseData = data;
    this.sortData(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
}
```

P.S. you can remove the parameters by using them directly:

```
sortData() {
  let fieldName = this.sortBy;
  let sortDirection = this.sortDirection;
```

And it's also highly more efficient to simply copy the array instead of JSON round-trip:

```
let parseData = [...this.data];
```